# MATLAB / vs Python np.linalg.solve, heat diffusion

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x, matlab

I am solving a simple 1D steady heat question using spectral method. I am a long time MATLAB and Mathematica user and trying to learn Python. I compare only linear solving times and Python is way slower than MATLAB, which doesn't feel right. Can you please tell me why Python is an order of magnitude slower for only even linear solve?

MATLAB code

```matlab
N=5000;
% HERE I AM JUST CREATING THE MATRIX FOR d/dx
Dhat=zeros(N+1,N+1);

for j=1:N;
for i=mod(j-1,2):2:j;
Dhat(i+1,j+1)=2*j;
end
end
Dhat(1,:)=Dhat(1,:)/2;
cbar=[2; ones(N-1,1); 2];
p=0:1:N;
pn=cos((pi/N)*kron(p',p));
I=ones(N+1,1);
II=(-1).^(0:N);
G=kron(I,II);
x=-cos(pi*(0:N)/N)';
T=G.*pn;
Tinv=(2/N)*(G'./kron(cbar,cbar')).*pn;

D=T*Dhat*Tinv;     % derivative matrix
% We have d/dx matrix

D2=D*D;            % d2/dx2 to solve d^2T/dx^2 = F

T0= 0;             % Temp at left boundary
Tn= 10;            % Temp at right boundary
F= zeros(N+1,1);   % source term
F(1)=0;            % Boundary condition
F(end)=10;         % Boundary condition

D2(1,:)=zeros;
D2(end,:)=zeros;
D2(1,1)=1;          % At the left boundary T = 0
D2(end,end)=1;      % At the right boundary T = 10
tic
T=D2/F';
toc
```

Python code

```py
def chebgl(N):
    import numpy as np
    cbar = np.array([1] * (N - 1))
    cbar = np.insert(cbar, 0, 2)
    cbar = np.insert(cbar, N, 2)

    p = np.array(range(N + 1))
    pkp = np.kron(p, p)
    pkp = pkp.reshape(N + 1, N + 1)
    pn = np.cos((np.pi / N) * pkp)

    I = np.ones(N + 1)
    Ia = -1 * np.ones(N + 1)
    II = np.power(Ia, range(N + 1))
    G = np.kron(I, II)
    G = G.reshape(N + 1, N + 1)

    T = np.multiply(G, pn)
    GTrans = np.transpose(G)

    cbarK = np.kron(cbar, cbar)
    cbarK = cbarK.reshape(N + 1, N + 1)

    Tinv = (2 / N) * np.multiply((np.divide(GTrans, cbarK)), pn)

    dhat = np.zeros((N + 1, N + 1))

    for j in range(1, N + 1, 1):

        for i in range((j - 1) % 2, j, 2):
            dhat[i, j] = 2 * j

    dhat[0] = dhat[0] / 2
    # This is the operator for d/dx

    D = np.matmul(np.matmul(T, dhat), Tinv)
    # predefined x-locations
    x = -np.cos(np.pi * (p / N))

    return D, x
```

Main code

```py
import numpy as np
import chebGL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import process_time

# Because I want to see all double precision digits
np.set_printoptions(precision=15)
# Number of points (d^2/dx^2) T = F(x) is going to be solved  
N = 5000

D, x = chebGL.chebgl(N)

T0 = 0  # Left boundary condition
Tend = 10  # Right boundary condition
F = 0 * np.ones(N + 1)  # Source Term
F[0] = T0  # inputting the boundary condition
F[N] = Tend  # inputting the boundary condition

D2T = np.matmul(D, D)  # Creating d^2/dx^2 operator
D2T[0] = abs(0 * D2T[0])
D2T[N] = abs(0 * D2T[0])

D2T[0, 0] = 1  # inputting the left boundary condition
D2T[N, N] = 1  # inputting the right boundary condition

t1_start = process_time()

T = np.linalg.solve(D2T, F)
t1_stop = process_time()

print("Elapsed time during the whole program in seconds:", t1_stop -
      t1_start)
```

Comment: @AJNeufeld No problem, if you can reproduce it, perhaps you can take it to meta :) But the saga continues. Now OP is editing from older revision. Oh boy, I bet this   question will end up with more edits than wished for.

Comment: I'm not sure this post asks for a code review.

Comment: @IEatBagels Depending on which revision you look at, it is. It's simply phrased a little iffy, but that's ok. There have been enough edits. Consider it a performance question, we've done plenty of those.

Comment: [This SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MATLAB+Python+slow+is%3Aquestion) currently yields 266 questions, most of which ask why Python is slower than MATLAB. It starts from the false premise that a program written in one language should be equally fast as the same program written in another language. All languages are different. Pick the one that is best suited to your problem. For linear algebra, pick MATLAB.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not asking for a review.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Mostly I disagree; if we (perhaps generously) interpret it as a run-of-the-mill performance improvement question then it seems on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you please tell me why Python is an order of magnitude slower for only even linear solve?

Answering this generically is perhaps a little off-topic for review, but: first, it's important that we check [the documentation for `solve()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html), which explains

> The solutions are computed using LAPACK routine `_gesv`.

For this solution step only, if MATLAB is indeed much faster, look at the fundamentals:

- Which flavour of BLAS does your instance of Numpy use? Have you used ATLAS? If not, why not?
- When you run your program, is there obvious occupancy of more than one CPU core? Does this change between MATLAB and Numpy?

Note that the slow parts of your program are **not** only between your `t1_start` and `t1_stop`. Any time that you do a matrix multiplication in `chebGL`, that's slow too. Since the dominant CPU time is spent in the lower-level matrix libraries and not Numpy itself, you can't blame Python itself for being slow - not even Numpy, necessarily; I would look to BLAS and make sure that the best implementation is selected and compiled correctly.

Though it doesn't make much of a difference in runtime, there's a long list of things you should work on in your usage of Numpy:

Don't call `np.insert`, and definitely don't use built-in list repetition. Create `cbar` at the correct size using `np.ones` and then overwrite the first and last entries with `2`.

Use `np.arange` instead of `range`.

I don't think that your use of the Kronecker product is appropriate. You can just multiply a vector by its transpose; no reshaping necessary.

Don't use `np.power` to get a vector of alternating 1, -1. Just use slice assignment on a vector and then broadcast to a matrix.

Prefer `.T` instead of `np.transpose`.

Prefer `*`, `/` and `@` operators instead of their corresponding functions `np.multiply`, `np.divide` and `np.matmul`.

You should not be recalculating `x`. Just negate the second row from `pn` which is equivalent.

Don't `0 * np.ones`; just call `np.zeros`.

`abs(0 *` is strange and unnecessary; just write `0`.

Add regression tests.

This:

> Elapsed time during the whole program in seconds:

is a lie, and is only the elapsed time during `np.linalg.solve`.

### Suggested

I believe this to be equivalent but you're going to want to scrutinise.

```py
import numpy as np
from time import process_time


def chebgl(N: int) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # D: (n+1)*(n+1)
    np.ndarray,  # x: (n+1)
]:
    cbar = np.ones((N + 1, 1))
    cbar[(0, -1), :] = 2
    cbarK = cbar * cbar.T

    p = np.arange(N + 1)[np.newaxis, :]
    pkp = p * p.T
    pn = np.cos(np.pi / N * pkp)

    g = np.ones_like(p)
    g[:, 1::2] = -1
    G = np.broadcast_to(g, pkp.shape)
    GTrans = G.T

    T = G * pn
    Tinv = 2 / N * GTrans / cbarK * pn

    # This is the operator for d/dx
    dhat = np.zeros_like(G)
    dhat[ ::2, 1::2] = np.arange(2,   2*N, 4)
    dhat[1::2,  ::2] = np.arange(0, 2+2*N, 4)
    dhat = np.triu(dhat)
    dhat[0, :] //= 2

    D = T @ dhat @ Tinv  # quite slow
    # predefined x-locations
    x = -pn[1, :]

    return D, x


def main() -> None:
    # Because I want to see all double precision digits
    np.set_printoptions(precision=15)
    # Number of points (d^2/dx^2) T = F(x) is going to be solved
    N = 5000

    D, x = chebgl(N)
    assert D.shape == (5001, 5001)
    assert x.shape == (5001,)

    T0 = 0     # Left boundary condition
    Tend = 10  # Right boundary condition
    F = np.zeros(N + 1)  # Source Term
    F[0] = T0    # inputting the boundary condition
    F[N] = Tend  # inputting the boundary condition

    D2T = D @ D  # Creating d^2/dx^2 operator
    D2T[(0, N), :] = 0
    D2T[0, 0] = 1  # inputting the left boundary condition
    D2T[N, N] = 1  # inputting the right boundary condition

    t1_start = process_time()
    T = np.linalg.solve(D2T, F)
    t1_stop = process_time()
    print("Elapsed time during the solve() in seconds:", t1_stop - t1_start)

    assert T.shape == (5001,)
    assert T.argmin() == 0
    assert T.argmax() == 5000
    assert np.isclose(0, T.min(),  rtol=0, atol=1e-7)
    assert np.isclose(5, T.mean(), rtol=0, atol=1e-7)
    assert np.isclose(5, T[2500],  rtol=0, atol=1e-7)
    assert np.isclose(10, T.max(), rtol=0, atol=1e-7)
    assert np.isclose(1.1434317494703112, T[1098], rtol=0, atol=1e-7)
    non_monotonic = np.count_nonzero(np.diff(T) < 0)
    assert non_monotonic == 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If the problem being solved has a specific structure, MATLAB’s `\ ` operator might be using [a different algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt4jslc-6) to find the solution. A 10x time difference then would be unsurprising. The rest of the answer is useful. +1